# Form results from website through email

Tags: css, email

I have a script on my site. I want to get the results in my email when someone submits their details. How do I do that?  My server only allow .css files; no .php or .asp.

Comment: Doest it allow JavaScript files?

Answer (score 0):

You can, in fact, have an HTML form prompt to send an email without *any* scripting whatsoever.

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:thedude@isgreat.com" enctype="text/plain">
  <input type="text" name="comment">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Submitting that form with the content "foobar" in the text field will invoke the user's mailto link handler (e.g. Mail.app, Outlook, etc) and prompt them to send a message with the contents of the form, like so:

```
To: thedude@isgreat.com
[other headers]

comment=foobar
```

Of course, they can change the message if they want. Oh, and your email address is ripe for harvesting, if you care.